# Check if a list of byte arrays contains a new byte array

Tags: java, arrays, list, collections, byte

I have a list of byte arrays and need to check if this list **doesn't** contain a new given byte array. If not, than I need to perform some action.

Right now, I'm trying to do it like this:

```
List<byte[]> listOFByteArrays = getListOfByteArrays();
byte[] newByteArray = getNewByteArray();

if (!listOfByteArrays.contains(newByteArray)){
// do some action
}
```

This doesn't work for me, it performs this `some action` in the if statement anyway.

What am I doing wrong and what is the right way to check it?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Of course it performs.. Your list doesn't contain `newByteArray`

Comment: An array is only equal to itself. So your list can't possibly contain `newByteArray` (unless `newByteArray`is not a new byte array, but one of the arrays stored in the list). You need to loop through the list and compare the **contents** of the byte arrays: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#equals-byte:A-byte:A-

Comment: @JBNizet Yes, you are right. I have to compare contents. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Java's `.contains(T)` simply performs an equality check on the argument. An array, however, is not equal to another array containing the same values, because all of the values are not checked and the comparison is done on their pointers.

As you already have two `byte[]`, the gruesome - but functional - way could be to simply... Iterate through the list, and use `java.util.Arrays.equals()`, which works wonders on primitive arrays.

```
List<byte[]> listOFByteArrays = getListOfByteArrays();
byte[] newByteArray = getNewByteArray();
boolean flag = false;

for(byte[] b : listOFByteArrays) {
    if(Arrays.equals(b,newByteArray)) { 
       flag = true; 
       break;
    }
}

if (!flag){
   // do stuff
}
```

Comment: Why are you using `Boolean` objects instead of straight-forward `boolean` values?

Comment: @Holger Pure force of habit, it serves no purpose here. I will edit it out.

Answer (score 1):

`List.contains` method use `equals` to check if the list contain specific element. 
From [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#contains-java.lang.Object-):

> Returns true if this list contains the specified element. More formally, returns true if and only if this list contains at least one element e such that Objects.equals(o, e).

But for arrays the `equals` method is the same as `==`. That's why `contains` returns false even if content is the same. Use [`Arrays.equals`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#equals-byte:A-byte:A-) instead:

```
for (byte[] arr : listOfByteArrays) {
    if (Arrays.equals(arr, newByteArray )) {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this

```
if (!listOFByteArrays
    .stream()
    .anyMatch(byteArray -> Arrays.areEqual(byteArray, newByteArray))) {

    // do some action
}
```

Comment: It can be modifeid like this:
    if (bytesPhotosInCloud
                    .stream()
                    .noneMatch(byteArray -> Arrays.equals(byteArray, bytesImage))){
                      //do some action
                    }

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for:

```
for (int i = 0; i < listOfByteArrays.size(); i++) {
    if (Arrays.equals(newByteArray, listOfByteArrays.get(i))) {
        //do some action
    }
}
```